# send main activity in background on button click and bring it back after a given time interval

Tags: android, time, background, fixed, foreground

I am new to android. My android application contains only one class.
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener

I want to send it in background on a button click and it comes in the foreground again after a fixed time interval.
how to implement this?